# How do I calculate how many spells per day a cleric has?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, spells

Ok so me and my group have just started getting into PF and we like it very much. But when we try to figure our spells per day for casters, we get confused.

Let's say a cleric on lvl 1 has 3 orisons and 1 1st level spell (1 more for +3 wis modifier) and one domain spell slot. Does this mean he can have 2 1st level spells and use each one two times? And can he also have two domain spells? Can you use them only once before you have to pray to your deity to get them refreshed?

Comment: Preemptively protected due to unfortunate keywords attracting spambots. Be welcome anonymous user.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. And once you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)!

Comment: sorta related question: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/15478/3358

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets go through a few things

- Clerics pray and prepare spells once per day, this determines all their spells for that day
- Clerics get [additional spells to prepare](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/gettingStarted.html#abilities-and-spellcasters) depending on their wisdom bonus. These spells (as well as their base spell allowance) are alignment restricted:

> Chaotic, Evil, Good, and Lawful Spells: A cleric can't cast spells of
>   an alignment opposed to her own or her deity's (if she has one).
>   Spells associated with particular alignments are indicated by the
>   chaotic, evil, good, and lawful descriptors in their spell
>   descriptions.

- Clerics get [one domain spell](http://paizo.com/prd/classes/cleric.html#domains) for each *spell level* they can cast (1st, 2nd, 3rd etc). Clerics have two domains and this bonus spell must be one of the spells from their domains for that level.
- Orisons can be used as often as you want during that day
- Spells Level 1+ are "used up" when cast, the cleric can't use them again until they've prayed again the next day
- Clerics can also [Spontaneously convert](http://paizo.com/prd/classes/cleric.html#spontaneous-casting-cleric) any of their spells (but not their bonus domain spell) into a cure or inflict spell of the same level.

So, the Level 1 Cleric with 1 bonus spell per day from wisdom.

Gets **3 Orisons** - These can be cast as often as they like.
Gets **2 level 1 spells** from any of the level 1 cleric spells. These can be spontaneously converted. Once cast, these are used up for the day.
Gets **1 level 1 spell** from their domain spells. Once cast this is used up for the day.

Example:

**Bob the Cleric of Chaos and Charm**

Bob has prepared the following Spells:
0: Light, Mending, Bleed
1: Protection From Law (Bob is allowed either Charm Person or Protection from Law from his domains)
1: Bless
1: Doom

Bob can cast Light, Mending and Bleed as much as he wants.
Bob can cast Protection from Law, Bless and Doom once each per Day.
Bob could, if he wanted to, take 2 "Doom" spells as his non-domain spells instead, and as a result could cast Doom twice per day - what he chooses for his spells is entirely up to him.

Don't forget also the clerics highly useful [channel energy](http://paizo.com/prd/classes/cleric.html#domains) ability!

Comment: Some classes do not have to prepare their spells in advance(like sorcerers and bards). These classes, instead know limited number of spells indicated by their spells known table and can only cast those spells. Any spellcasting class that doesnt have that table must prepare their spells in advance. The trade-off is they generally have a wider repertoir but can cast less spells per day.

Comment: @CanCanbek - The trade off is having a wider repertory (and I don't know if PF still has longer casting time on spontaneous metamagic) versus casting more spells per day **and** choosing them on the spot.